# EF Bulk insert creates duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to build a tool that will populate my test DB. Essentially it's a bulk insert broken up into batches of 20 (for now) as the context seems to be getting slower and slower as it grows.

```
int records = 43;
int disposeAfter = 20;
var _localContext = new DB(false);
_localContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

for (int i = 1; i <= records; i++)
 {    
     Communication item = new Communication();
     ....set all the item properties, etc..

    _localContext.Communications.Add(item);
    if (i % disposeAfter == 0)
       {
           _localContext.SaveChanges();
           _localContext.Dispose();               
           _localContext = new DB(false);
           _localContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        } 
} 
_localContext.SaveChanges();
```

Problem is that after this runs through. I have more than 43 records in the database. I stepped through the loop and it seems that AFTER the first `saveChanges()` call, `_localContext.Communications.Add(item);` call has a chance of pulling some of the records it already inserted with the first `saveChanges()` call into the context. Which then get saves again when it's time for another `saveChanges()` call.

I am at a loss...
Below is the my `DB` class.

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EF.Communication.Communication> Communications { get; set; }

    public DB()
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public DB(bool verbose)
    {
        if (verbose)
            this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommunicationConfig());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DbContext` shouldn't be pulling data if not requested. Can you provide a repro (`mcve`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev I am not sure how I can provide it in a form you can run. That's kind of all there is to it. I added my `DbContext` class. Is here anything in particular you'd like to see? Thanks!

Comment: Probably the model `Communication`. Is it flat, i.e. are there some FK and navigation properties? And is the posted code exact? Btw, why don't you turn your `DbContext` log on (pass `true` to the constructor) and see what happens.